# rsync: is there an option to make rsync stop at first error so i can see what's happening?

Tags: rsync

CONTEXT : rsync with very large number of files to sync

WHAT HAPPENS : rsync encounters errors, but just continues.....

WHAT I DO : `rsync -Pav path1 path2`

ISSUE : I'm booted in a recovery mode and the recovery drive have no space left...

QUESTIONS : is there an option to make rsync stop at first error so I can see what's happening ?

I TRIED to look man page of rsync, but cannot find any option that would suggest stop at first error

Comment: Why not use the `-verbose` option?

Comment: @Davidw I use `rsync -Pav` v for verbose. but the files goes too quickly and I have to ctrl+c to force it to stop to check what is the error

Comment: You could use `-q` or just redirect stderr somewhere so you can review all the errors at once when it finishes.

Comment: @MichaelHampton is there any way to not wait until finish ? just simply stop at first error ? with verbose I see errors passing, and rsync continues... I just want rsync to stop or pause if it encounter any error

Comment: I could not find such a way. But I would be OK with letting it run all the way, if I can get all the errors at once (so I can hopefully resolve them all at once and not waste time re-running rsync each time).

Comment: Why waiting until it is finished? You can read the log file on another terminal while rsync is still running.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider That is true. You could start working on the first error even as more errors come in and the sync continues toward a mostly complete operation, saving even more time.

Answer (score 2):

> ISSUE : I'm booted in a recovery mode and the recovery drive have no
> space left...
>
> QUESTIONS : is there an option to make rsync stop at first error so I can see what's happening ?

Unfortunately, it seems rsync does not support this at the moment. There is an issue about this on GitHub:  [#71 rsync does not terminate when target disk is full](https://github.com/WayneD/rsync/issues/71). There, Wayne Davison (rsync's maintainer) writes:

> Since this problem is inherent in the way rsync works and there is a
> work-around fix, I'm closing this bug. A future rsync 4.0 will
> hopefully not have this issue.

The issue also lists using `--msgs2stderr` as a workaround, you could try that, it should at least make rsync exit more quickly.